# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass | ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did a project to perform *add*, *delete* and *edit* records. I got error when tried to edit record.

`index.erb`,

```
<h1>Baza Filmow</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <td>Tytul</td>
      <td>Reżyser</td>
      <td>Pozycja</td>
      <td>Czy w kinach</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Akcja</td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <% @wszyscy.each do |w| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= w.tytul %></td>
    <td><%= w.rezyser %></td>
    <td><%= w.pozycja %></td>
    <td><%= w.czy_w_kinach %></td>
    <td><%= w.data %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Usuń", {id: w.id, action: 'usun'}, data:{confirm: 'Czy na pewno?'}, class: 'btn btn-warning'%> </td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edytuj", {id: w.id, action: 'edytuj'}, class: 'btn btn-info'%> </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
```

To edit records,

```
<%= form_for @edytowany, url: {action: "aktualizuj", id: @film.id} do |f| %>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <td>Tytuł</td>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:tytul) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Reżyser</td>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:rezyser) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pozycja</td>
        <td><%= f.select :pozycja, (1..20), {include_blank: "Wybierz"} %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Czy w kinach?</td>
        <td><%= f.check_box(:czy_w_kinach) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Czy w kinach?</td>
        <td><%= f.date_select(:data) %></td>
      </tr></table>
    <td><%= f.submit "Aktualizuj", class:'btn btn-primary' %></td>

<% end %>
```

In `routes.rb`,

```
  get 'film/index'   
  get 'film/utworz'   
  get 'film/usun'   
  get 'film/edytuj'   
  root 'film#index'

  match 'utworz', to: 'film#utworz', :via => [:post, :get]   
  match 'index', to: 'film#index', :via => [:post, :get]
  match 'film/dodaj' => 'film#dodaj', via: [:get, :post]   
  match 'film/usun' => 'film#usun', via: [:get, :post]   
  match 'film/edytuj' => 'film#edytuj', via: [:get, :post, :patch]
```

Comment: could you please post where the error occurs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to state what your problem is. What is happening that you are not expecting? You probably just have a typo in your code somewhere but it's much easier to troubleshoot if you tell us what is happening or not happening that you define as "wrong". Also have you taken any troubleshooting steps yourself?

Comment: Also add your controller code.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should be a bit more specific in your questions, and as already stated also put your controller code in the question.

At a first glance I would say you are not defining @film in your edit action in the controller

```
def edit
  @film = #Do your film lookup here.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution as I understand your question

I think You should pass id of `@edytowany` not `@file.id`

You can find below link for more knowledge 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/form_helpers.html